# Why can't I find files that have py extension?

Tags: python

The below codes can find files that have a particular file extension. But same codes can't find files that have py extension. What is the reason for that?

**search.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os


def search(dir_or_file):
    if dir_or_file.startswith("*."):
        return [
            os.path.join(i, m) 
            for i, j, k in os.walk("/")
            for m in k
            if m.endswith("." + dir_or_file.split(".")[1])
        ]        
    else:
        return [
            os.path.join(i, dir_or_file) 
            for i, j, k in os.walk("/") 
            if dir_or_file in k or dir_or_file in j
        ]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        for i in search(sys.argv[1]):
            print(i)
```

When I run the `search.py` script to search for files that have `*.txt` extension, I am getting the below output:

```
tanberk@kutlu:~$ ./search.py *.txt
/media/tanberk/Data/Belgeler/İş Başvurusu/a.txt
/media/tanberk/Data/Projects/astrology/a.txt
/home/tanberk/a.txt
/home/tanberk/Projects/astrology/a.txt
tanberk@kutlu:~$
```

**Note:** By the way there are many files that have `*.txt` extension. The program can not find all of them.

When I run the `search.py` script to search for files that have `*.py` extension, I am getting the below output:

```
tanberk@kutlu:~$ ./search.py *.py
tanberk@kutlu:~$
```

Comment: "By the way there are many files that have txt extension. The program can not find all of them." I would try to understand why *that* happens first.

Comment: I found that strange too.

Comment: same result, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Your shell is expanding the pattern before your script sees it. You find all the `a.txt` files because `*.txt` expands to `a.txt` from your home directory (and you apparently have no other `.txt` files in your home directory), so the *real* command you ran was `./search.py a.txt`, and all you see are files named `a.txt`.

At a guess, the reason you see nothing for `*.py` is because you have multiple `.py` files in your home directory, and your script explicitly does nothing if `len(sys.argv)` is anything other than `2`. When the shell expands `*.py`, you end up with a too long `sys.argv` (because it actually ran something like `./search.py foo.py search.py ...`) and do nothing.

To run your script as you expect (with the script interpreting the wildcards), quote your inputs to prevent shell expansion, e.g.:

```sh
$ ./search.py '*.txt'
```

I also suggest you change your argument processing to produce a usage message when it receives the wrong number of arguments; usage errors should never pass silently.

Comment: When I search the mp3 files, the program finds all the mp3 files but when I search the txt files, the program can't find all the txt files. What is the reason for that different behavior? And when I change the search pattern, nothing changes. py files can not be found.

Comment: @dildeolupbiten: I'm going to guess you don't have *any* `.mp3` files in the working directory where you began the search (the root of your home directory, if you ran it like the others). When `nullglob` isn't enabled in `bash` (which is the default IIRC), when the pattern doesn't match any files, `bash` passes along the pattern directly without expanding it. So your test for `if dir_or_file.startswith("*."):` actually passes (unlike in the `*.txt` case where it got `a.txt`, and the `*.py` case where the test was never even reached), and you do the wildcarding yourself.

Comment: It begins to search in `/` directory. The program even can find the files which are at the mounted `D:` driver. I have also `.txt` files there. The `.mp3` files that are stored in `D:` can be found but the `.txt` files which are stored in `D:` can not be found. Isn't that strange?

Comment: @dildeolupbiten: It's not strange at all. The *shell*, not Python at all, is paying attention to your *working* directory before your *script* gets involved at all. So if no `.mp3` files are in your home directory (which is where you're running the script from), then the shell doesn't expand `*.mp3`, and your script can begin its search from `/`. When the shell expands `*.txt` in your home directory, it finds `a.txt`, so your script would only be looking for `a.txt` files (Does `D:` have any?). It doesn't look for `*.txt` files, you (after shell expansion) said to look *only* for `a.txt`.

Comment: Ok, I changed the codes and the problem is solved. Thanks for your helps.